# ¿Cómo mantener un total e ir sumándole o restándole en un ciclo for?

Tags: c, algoritmos, ciclos

Necesito resolver el siguiente problema, tengo que realizar un algoritmo que lea `30` consumos, si el consumo es mayor a `50` pesos que se le haga un descuento del `7%`, mostrar todos los pagos y el pago total o acumulado,

Hice esto hasta ahora pero no me suma los pagos con sus descuentos, creo que necesito una variable donde me guarde los descuentos y otra variable donde me guarde los pagos y luego los restos.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () {
    int consumo,suma=0,total,contador=0,desc,calc1;
    printf("Ingrese los consumos: ");
    for(contador=1;contador<=30;contador++){
    scanf("%d",&consumo);
    if(consumo>50){
        calc1=consumo*0.07;
        desc=consumo-calc1;
        }
    else
    suma=suma+consumo;
    total=desc+suma;
    }
    printf("\nEl pago total es de: %d ",total);
}
```

> Solo puedo usar decisiones `(if-else)` y ciclo `for`.  No puedo usar arreglos ni ningún método.

Comment: a que llamas pagos?? pq en ningun lado dice pagos esto.. si no consumos... y fijate que hay un problema.. total se suma solo si el consumo no es mayor que 50....

Comment: llamo pagos a los consumos

Comment: En SO estamos para resolver problemas que surgen al programar, mas no para resolver tus tareas. Con un poco de depuración podrias encontrar la solución a tu tarea. Esta pregunta no ayuda a mejorar a la comunidad de SO en español.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, Gustavo. Está claro que te has esforzado en resolver por ti mismo esa pregunta, no estabas tan lejos de la solución. Vas por buen camino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es **identar bien**. Un programa mal identado es difícil de entender y de depurar.
Y vamos añadir unos printf que nos muestren lo que va haciendo el programa:

```
int main () {
    int consumo,suma=0,total,contador=0,desc,calc1;
    printf("Ingrese los consumos: ");
    for(contador=1;contador<=30;contador++){
        scanf("%d",&consumo);
        if(consumo>50){
            calc1=consumo*0.07;
            desc=consumo-calc1;
        }
        else 
            suma=suma+consumo;
        printf("El pago descontado es:%d\n", desc );
        printf("El pago es:%d\n", suma );
        total=desc+suma;
        printf("El total es:%d\n", total);
    }
    printf("\nEl pago total es de: %d ",total);
}
```

Ahora ejecutamos ese programa e introducimos 3 consumos: 70 20 60

> Ingrese los consumos: 70
>
> El pago descontado es:66
>   El pago es:0
>   El total es:66
>   20
>   El pago descontado es:66
>   El pago es:20
>   El total es:86
>   60
>   El pago descontado es:56
>   El pago es:20
>   El total es:76

Como puedes ver en la primera ejecución, con consumo 70, nos da buen resultado.
En la segunda, con consumo 20, el resultado también es correcto. El total es 86. Pero aquí observamos que en pago descontado se ha quedado 66, el valor de la iteración anterior.
Y en la tercera iteración, con consumo 60, tenemos el error. Nuestro total ha bajado de 86 a 76 en vez de subir que es lo que debía hacer. Si te fijas ese 76 es 20+56 que es justo lo que valen las variables desc y suma en ese momento.
Pero tu no querías 76. Tu lo que quieres es 86 (lo acumulado hasta entonces) + 56 (el nuevo pago descontado). Es decir, quieres sumar al total que llevabas el nuevo pago descontado.

Esto lo haces substituyendo la línea `total=desc+suma;` por :

```
    total = total + desc;
```

Y además vamos a inicializar las variables a 0:

```
int consumo=0,suma=0,total=0,contador=0,desc=0,calc1=0;
```

Si ejecutas el programa con esas dos modificaciones (**hazlo**) verás que ahora el total sí va aumentando. Pero ahora hay otro grave problema, solo se suman los pagos descontados, no se suman los otros pagos. Y, peor aún, cuando hay un pago sin descuento se suma el precio del anterior pago descontado.
Esto es porque hemos hecho que en el total se acumule el pago descontado olvidándonos del otro. Vamos a solucionarlo sumando los dos, usa ahora :

```
    total = total + suma + desc;
```

Y para que funcione bien nos vamos a asegurar de que el valor que no usamos valga cero :

```
    if(consumo>50){
        calc1=consumo*0.07;
        desc=consumo-calc1;
        suma = 0; // En pagos descontados no se usa esto
    }
    else {
        suma=consumo;
        desc = 0 ; // En pagos sin descuento no se usa esto
    }
```

Aquí ya tienes algo que se parece mucho a la solución que buscas.
Ahora toca quitar algunos printf que ya no necesitamos para depurar. Y poner los que sea oportuno para que se imprima como necesitas. Pero seguro que esto ya lo puedes hacer tu.